# Tkinter programs opening 2 windows problem

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.7

I am trying to create a bank program in tkinter where you login and register, but a problem happens when I try to run it. When I run the first file, it opens the window 2 times, which is what I do not want.

This is my main file:

```
from Login import *
from time import *
from tkinter import *

#Frame Setup########
root = Tk()
root.title("Main_File")
root.configure(bg="SeaGreen")
var = Frame(root)
var.configure(bg=var.master['bg'])
var.grid()

Login(var)

def LogClicked():
    print("Log")

def RegClicked():
    print("Reg")
```

This is my second file:

```
from tkinter import *

def Login(Log):
    import Main_File
    #First Name#########
    L1 = Label(Log, text="First Name:")
    L1.configure(font=("Courier", 35),bg=L1.master['bg'], fg="Gold")
    L1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(50, 0), pady=(100, 0))
    FirstN = Entry(Log)
    FirstN.configure(width=50)
    FirstN.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(100, 0))

    #Last Name##########
    L2 = Label(Log, text="Last Name:")
    L2.configure(font=("Courier", 35),bg=L2.master['bg'], fg="Gold")
    L2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(50, 0), sticky=W)
    LastN = Entry(Log)
    LastN.configure(width=50)
    LastN.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #Login Button#######
    LogB = Button(Log, text="Login", command = lambda : Main_File.LogClicked())
    LogB.configure(font=("Courier", 15),bg=LogB.master['bg'],     activebackground=LogB.master['bg'], width=25)
    LogB.grid(row=3, column=1)

    #Register Button####
    RegB = Button(Log, text="Register", command = lambda : Main_File.RegClicked())
    RegB.configure(font=("Courier", 15),bg=RegB.master['bg'], activebackground=RegB.master['bg'], width=25)
    RegB.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Now no matter what, I always have to run the main file first. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `import Main_File` from Login.py. You are importing the whole module which includes the creation of Tk(), hence the added window. Also it is much preferred to use `import tkinter as tk` instead of the global import `from tkinter import *`.

If you must retain Main_file and Login as separate files, you can try the below:

```
from Login import Login
from time import *
from tkinter import *

#Frame Setup########
root = Tk()
root.title("Main_File")
root.configure(bg="SeaGreen")
var = Frame(root)
var.configure(bg=var.master['bg'])
var.grid()

Login(var)

root.mainloop()
```

2nd file:

```
from tkinter import *

def Login(Log):
    #First Name#########
    L1 = Label(Log, text="First Name:")
    L1.configure(font=("Courier", 35),bg=L1.master['bg'], fg="Gold")
    L1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(50, 0), pady=(100, 0))
    FirstN = Entry(Log)
    FirstN.configure(width=50)
    FirstN.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(100, 0))

    #Last Name##########
    L2 = Label(Log, text="Last Name:")
    L2.configure(font=("Courier", 35),bg=L2.master['bg'], fg="Gold")
    L2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(50, 0), sticky=W)
    LastN = Entry(Log)
    LastN.configure(width=50)
    LastN.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def LogClicked():
        print("Log")

    def RegClicked():
        print("Reg")

    #Login Button#######
    LogB = Button(Log, text="Login", command = lambda : LogClicked())
    LogB.configure(font=("Courier", 15),bg=LogB.master['bg'],     activebackground=LogB.master['bg'], width=25)
    LogB.grid(row=3, column=1)

    #Register Button####
    RegB = Button(Log, text="Register", command = lambda : RegClicked())
    RegB.configure(font=("Courier", 15),bg=RegB.master['bg'], activebackground=RegB.master['bg'], width=25)
    RegB.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Comment: The only problem is that I want the regclicked and logclicked in the main file because I am going to create more files like login and I want the main file to be the “brain” of the operation and the login.py and all others to be the look of the operation

Comment: if you want the main file to be the brain, then why does the other files need to import from the main file?

Comment: The reason I make the import files have to import the main file is because I want it so when a button gets pressed, it activates the function in the main file. The reason I want it to activate a function from the main file because later I am going to change the print(“regclicked”) to a way where the register frame activates